# Can you reduce the risk involved in an uncertain event?

Tags: probability, uncertainty, definition, risk

I'm not sure if this is the right Stack Exchange site but I felt it came closest.

Based on Knights 1971 definition of risk uncertainty is defined as a situation where factors exogenous to the decision making process impact that event. The example given in his book is when an individual knows there are red and blue balls in a bucket but is unaware there are 5 red balls compared to 3 blue ball. He wrongly (due to uncertainty) assumes he has a 0.5 chance of picking red. In contrast to this risk can only be used when the uncertainty surrounding an event has been defined using a probability distribution. Using the above example another individual would face risk if he knew the distribution of balls in the bucket.

So my question is what do you call it when you reduce the probability that a hazard will occur from an uncertain event. For example say in the above game you won £20 when you picked a red ball and lost £20 when you picked a blue ball. Would you still say you were reducing risk if say you changed the rules of the game so you get to pick three times and you only lose £20 if you pick all three blue balls. The situation is still uncertain but have you not reduced the probability of losing?

Comment: Many, many researchers and practitioners of risk assessment today would dispute the assumption that "risk can only be used when the uncertainty surrounding an event has been defined using a probability distribution."  See almost any issue of *Risk Analysis* for counterexamples.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the comment. So what would the modern definition of risk be and how is that separated from uncertainty? Thanks for your help, its very hard to find cohesive information on this topic

Comment: Recent work is represented in a draft [glossary](http://www.sra.org/sra-glossary-draft) by the Society for Risk Analysis. It currently provides seven definitional interpretations of the ISO definition of "risk as the effect of uncertainty on objectives." Although several of these interpretations invoke probability, several do not, instead using words like "possibility," "potential," and "uncertainty." In the literature the latter have been quantified in various non-probabilistic ways, such as fuzziness, "info-gap" measures, "possibility distributions," intervals, and others.

Comment: Thank you, that glossary is incredibly helpful. Could you write up that comment as an answer and I can accept it.

Comment: Thank you, but I do not see how my comments actually answer your question, which currently is "what do you call it when you reduce the probability that a hazard will occur from an uncertain event?"

Comment: I think it does, it points out that the definition used by Knight is not commonly accepted. Therefore you can call "reducing the probability that a hazard will occur from an uncertain event" reducing the risk as risk does not require a fully described probability distribution. Therefore Knights definition is flawed?

Comment: I wouldn't characterize Knight's definition as "flawed." It's older--the SRA wasn't founded until a decade later. Risk is a fuzzy concept, which is why the glossary doesn't attempt to provide a single definition. I actually like your quotation a lot: "a situation where factors exogenous to the decision making process impact that event." It's practical, general, and appears to cover just about all the possibilities the glossary envisages. It's your subsequent statement, that "risk can *only* be used ... [with] a probability distribution," that is problematic. Did Knight really assert that?

Comment: He didn't explicitly state that the term risk could _only_ be used with a probability distribution but he did explicitly separate the concepts of risk and uncertainty based on a description of a probability distribution. I took that to mean that you can't talk about risk in situations where there is no probability distribution.

Comment: Knight's work antedates a seminal paper of Daniel Ellsberg who discusses a ball-in-urn kind of problem where even Bayesian risk analysts do not behave in a Bayesian fashion (that is, they instinctively react in a way that is inconsistent with subjective probability theory).  This is now known as the [Ellsberg paradox](http://www.ellsberg.net/documents/Risk_Ambiguity.pdf). His paper begins, "Are There Uncertainties That Are Not Risks?" See especially comments in the footnotes and some quotations of Kenneth Arrow.

Comment: So the idea would be that you can have risks with known probabilities and risks with unknown? So the answer to my question would still be "reducing risk"?

Comment: It's hard to say, because your question is framed explicitly in terms of probabilities in a situation where non-probabilistic models might be applied. Even so, it seems that the rules change you propose could not increase risk, whether or not the risk was modeled with probability.

Comment: I think I'll take it to be reducing risk. A real world analogy would be: is it called reducing risk of negative impacts of climate change. We don't know the probability of a drought occurring so what do you call it when you add irrigation. Is that reducing vulnerability? There seems to be significant cross over in these terms.

Answer (score 2):

The following may help:

(a) Frank Knight's seminal work on risk versus uncertainty is arguably his book "Risk, Uncertainty and Profit" published in 1921. Risk managers often use the terms "risk" and "uncertainty" largely interchangeably (in line with how they are used by the general public). However, when they do attempt to differentiate between these two terms then they usually do so in the way that he did in his book, using the term "uncertainty" in a similar sense to how economists use the term "[Knightian uncertainty](http://www.nematrian.com/ERMGlossaryKnightianUncertainty.aspx)" (this link should provide a definition of this term and should also take you to further information on Knight's book).

(b) In his book, Knight focused on the relevance of this distinction to business life, especially the role of entrepreneurs. Suppose we toss a fair coin. Then we can identify the (exact) probability of the coin coming up heads. But suppose we are a smartphone manufacturer and we decide to launch a new smartphone. It is not normally possible to know in advance exactly how profitable a new product will be or even to quantify accurately the probability of any given level of profitability being achieved. The outcome is inherently "uncertain" (i.e. even the probabilities involved cannot be accurately quantified) and not just "risky", using his terminology. Knight's insight was to realise that entrepreneurs do this all the time, presumably hoping to gain some reward over time from doing so.

(c) So to answer your title question, one way of reducing the risk involved in an uncertain event is to avoid being "entrepreneurial", e.g. if you are a smartphone manufacturer then you could stop bringing out any new smartphones on the grounds that this minimises your likelihood of failure. Of course, shareholders may take a dim view if a firm adopts such a strategy across its entire range of business activities, because (as Frank Knight noted) some element of entrepreneurship is in the nature of doing business.

(d) You also ask "what do you call it when you reduce the probability that a hazard will occur from an uncertain event". Presumably by "hazard" you mean "suffering a negative impact from the event". You can reduce the probability of this occurring by "hedging" the risk / uncertainty or by "taking out insurance" against the risk / uncertainty etc.. Of course, in a business context doing so usually involves giving up some of the potential upside that might otherwise accrue from the uncertain event.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer; part a) and b) are a really nice summary. In terms of part d) I assumed a similar definition of hazard to you. So your answer is that its called 'hedging the risk' or `hedging the uncertainty' as they are both interchangable? Is this term equivalent to reducing the risk: is hedging not just one way of reducing risk/uncertainty? The example I gave reduced risk without hedging. Thanks for any clarification you can provide.

Comment: I'm not aware of there being any specific term for changing the rules of a game so that the likelihoods of different outcomes are changed (as in your example). Usually the assumption is that you will be facing some risks or uncertainties and you want somehow to respond to them e.g. by reducing the negative impact they might have on you. There is no single (technical) term that captures all possible responses. "Hedging", if used generically, would capture many potential responses, although it can also be used in the more technical sense of entering into an additional offsetting transaction.

Comment: So to apply this to a real world scenario. Im a farmer facing climate change and associated uncertainty about droughts, wet periods, temperature changes etc. If I add irrigation am I reducing risks of my crops failing due to climate change? Hedging risks doesn't seem to make sense in this analogy. As you mention it may be that there just isnt a term for it. I guess it could also be referred to as reducing vulnerability to states which are uncertain.